# Derivative from integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Given: $f(t)=(\int_0^{\sqrt{t}}e^{-x^2} dx)^2$ and $g(t)=\int_0^1\frac{e^{-t(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2}$ for $t>0$.

Find: $f'(t)+g'(t)$.

Comment: What were your attempts?

Comment: Check out this, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: Actually it's the first time I came across such a problem. Could you show me how to apply this rule here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By differentiation under the integral sign,
$$ g'(t) = -\int_{0}^{1} e^{-t(1+x^2)}\,dx=-\frac{1}{e^t}\int_{0}^{1}e^{-tx^2}\,dx\tag{1} $$
and through the substitution $x=\sqrt{z}$ we have
$$ h(t) = \int_{0}^{\sqrt{t}}e^{-x^2}\,dx = \int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{z}}e^{-z}\,dz \tag{2}$$
so by the fundamental theorem of Calculus it follows that $h'(t)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}e^{-t}$.
Since $f(t)=h(t)^2$ we have $f'(t)=2 h'(t) h(t)$, i.e.
$$ f'(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}e^{t}}\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{z}}e^{-z}\,dz =\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}e^t}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{t}}e^{-z^2}\,dz=\frac{1}{e^t}\int_{0}^{1}e^{-tx^2}\,dx\tag{3}$$
and $f'(t)+g'(t)=\color{red}{\large 0}$.

Answer (score 2):

**hint for $f'$**

$$f (t)=(F (\sqrt {t}))^2$$
with
$$F (X)=\int_0^Xe^{-x^2}dx$$
thus

$$f'(t)=2\int_0^{\sqrt {t}}e^{-x^2}dx \frac {e^{-t}}{2\sqrt {t}} $$